# Help with discount rule Magento (buy x with attribute y and get z discount)

Tags: magento-1.6, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am wondering if it is possible to create a rule like this with default Magento.

In my shop i have different brands
I want to create a rule like this:

Buy 2 products of brand A and get 25% discount (only on products with Brand A).

Currently i have this setup:

**Condition:**

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE 
    If total quantity  equals or greater than  2  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:
        Brand is  Triumph
```

**Action:**

```
Apply: Percent of product price discount
Discount amount: 25 

Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    Brand is Triumh
```

Right now it gives correct discount on only Brand = Triumph, but it gives discount no matter how many products are in cart.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out myself :)

Under conditions it needs to look like this:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    If total quantity  equals or greater than  2  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: 
        Brand  is  Triumph
        Row total in cart  equals or greater than  2
```

Under action it looks like this:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    Brand  is  Triumph
```